# Send dialog doesn't work in page tab

Tags: javascript, facebook, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk

Send dialog doesn't work in iframe page tab.

did as in example on 'Send Dialog' page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

```
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      // assume we are already logged in
      FB.init({appId: '123050457758183', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

      FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
          link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
          });
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But this returns error:

```
API Error Code: 3
API Error Description: Unknown method
Error Message: Unknown method
```

but when change to 'feed' dialog everything works perfectly.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, there is a new [bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/246637628719849) tracking. This seems like a pretty serious limitation to me. There is no way to send from a FB tab without using a popup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a filed bug about it [here](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18942). One solution is suggested though is to use `display: 'popup'`